# Hard and Soft Assertions in TestNG

Tags: testng

I was trying some examples with hard and soft assertions in TestNG.while softassertions are working as expected, I am facing problem with hard assertions.

As per information I read from internet-If a hard assertion fails it does not execute other tests.

from below code-printTest3() test should have been skipped because ffPageElementsTestHardAssert() has failed. can some one help me understand this behavior..Thanks

```
@BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");  

       TestBase.startBrowser("firefox","http://newtours.demoaut.com/index.php");
       Assert.assertEquals(TestBase.getBasePageTitle(), "Welcome: Mercury Tours");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();         
       APP_LOGS.info("Page displayed");  
       lp = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
       ffPage = lp.doLogin("test", "test");
       sa = new SoftAssert();
  }  


  @Test(priority = 2)
  public void ffPageElementsTestHardAssert() {
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_Type_oneway.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_Type_roundtrip.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_PassengerCount.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_DepartingFrom.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_DepartingMonth.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_DepartingDay.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ArrivingIn.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ReturningMonth.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ReturningDay.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ServiceClass_EC.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ServiceClass_BC.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_ServiceClass_FC.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_Airline.isDisplayed());
     Assert.assertTrue(ffPage.ff_Continue.isDisplayed());   
  }


  @Test(priority = 1)
  public void printTest1(){
      Assert.assertEquals(5, 5);
  }

  @Test(priority = 3)
  public void printTest3(){
      System.out.println("Hello3");
  }



   Output:
    -------
    Hello3
    PASSED: printTest1
    PASSED: printTest3
    FAILED: ffPageElementsTestHardAssert
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"airlin"}
    Command duration or timeout: 65 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
    System info: host: 'PSHYS0091', ip: '10.233.18.60', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
    Session ID: da04681e-4918-4d75-94ee-ff590464c7c5
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=31.6.0}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:299)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
        at com.nt.tests.FlightFinderTest.ffPageElementsTestHardAssert(FlightFinderTest.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"airlin"}
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
    System info: host: 'PSHYS0091', ip: '10.233.18.60', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'



    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main difference is:

**HardAssert** - throws AssertException immediately, test is marked as failed and test suite continues with next `@Test`

**SoftAssert** - collects errors during `@Test` (no exception is thrown) and if you call `org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert#assertAll` at **the end of `@Test`** exception is thrown if there was any and test suite again continue with next `@Test`

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav...if I have a group of assertions in a Test and if my first assertion fails, other assertions in the Test will not be executed?

Comment: Exactly, if hard assert fails other assertions will not be executed and test fails immediately. If soft assertion fails all other soft assertions will be executed and at the end of test you have to call assertAll to check result (it's something like one hard assert for all soft asserts)

Comment: One observation: If there is a assertion error, then SoftAssert will continue with next assertion and will throw error at end and continue with next test, But if there is a exception eg; element not found exception, then it will not continue with next assertions. I can use try..catch to overcome this, is there any other way?

Comment: Sure, if your test throws exception TestNG handle it (mark test as failed) and next `@Test` continues. If you expect exception you can use `@Test(expectedExceptions = {})` but it's not this case. Otherwise you have to design your tests properly (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects etc.)